# Bootstrap DatePicker no formato mm/yyyy definir data máxima

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Estou usando Bootstrap DatePicker no formato mm/yyyy, mas estou com problemas definir a maior data possível.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O Código está assim:

```
$('#mesVigencia').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    language: 'pt-BR'
})
```

Como definir o mês atual como sendo o maior mês selecionável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O máximo se torna hoje.

```
$( "#mesVigencia" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "+0m +0w"
});
```

Ou

```
$( "#mesVigencia" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+0m +0w" );
```

**UPDATE**

Tenta definir como var.

```
var date2 = new Date();

date2.setDate(date2.getDate());

maxDate:date2
```

Comment: Não funcionou, continuo conseguindo selecionar meses futuros.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, tenta novamente. Tenta ver o console se tem algum erro de js.

Comment: Cara, também não funcionou, e não há erros no console. Já tentei várias dicas que achei aqui no SO e nenhuma funcionou até agora.

Comment: Tenta definir com var então.